# Converting String of comma seperated double values to list

Tags: python, string, list, double

An external method returns me the following string,
`[875.5599999999476,-223155.0180000058,766.8799999999985,1830.867499999997]\n`.

I have to convert it to a list.

Comment: It's a;ready a list

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a task for [`literal_eval`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = literal_eval('[875.5599999999476,-223155.0180000058,766.8799999999985,1830.867499999997]')
```

This will give you the list `[875.5599999999476, -223155.0180000058, 766.8799999999985, 1830.867499999997]`.

Comment: Note that `literal_eval` will also accept a lot of other data types (though that may be okay).

Comment: Yes it will, but it's not dangerous as `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it valid JSON? If so, you could use `json.loads()`. Otherwise:

```
s = '[875.5599999999476,-223155.0180000058,766.8799999999985,1830.867499999997]'
lst = [float(item) for item in s[1:-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

probably a more elegant way of doing it but maybe something like:

```
x.strip("[").strip("]").split(",")
```

EDIT:

As noted in the comments below, the above code will not convert the numbers in the string to floats. To do this, see below:

```
[float(i) for i in x.strip("[").strip("]").split(",")]
```

Comment: What about `x[1:-1].split(',')`?

Comment: ah nice one! Should have thought of that!

Comment: Will it also convert numbers in that string to the appropriate Python type?

Answer (score 1):

IS this what you want:

```
l = [875.5599999999476,-223155.0180000058,766.8799999999985,1830.867499999997]
print (l)
```

Output:

```
[875.5599999999476, -223155.0180000058, 766.8799999999985, 1830.867499999997]
```

or split each item in a list?

```
l = [875.5599999999476,-223155.0180000058,766.8799999999985,1830.867499999997]
for x in l:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
875.5599999999476
-223155.0180000058
766.8799999999985
1830.867499999997
```